# Rounding Math Equations

Tags: python, math, rounding

How can I make my conversion of Celsius to Fahrenheit line of show string round to the tenth?  My current output prints out with a ton of zeros at the end.

```
def on_forever():
  basic.show_string("" + (input.temperature() * 1.8 + 32))
  basic.show_string("F")
basic.forever(on_forever)
```

Comment: There is a `round` function: `str(round(int(input.temperature() * 1.8 + 32), x))`. Just change `x` to the number of decimal places you want.

Comment: There is also string formatting - `formatted = '{.1f}'.format(value)` where `.1f` defines the number of decimal places.  It will round up, for example `1.46 -> 1.5`.

Comment: Thank you both, @EliHarold and Snakecharmerb.  I knew the round function was a thing.  I was just messing up my use of it and got all confused and got rid of the rounding part to show.  Figured it'd be easier to add on top of working code.

Comment: It's formatting that you need here, not rounding. The `round` function doesn't really give you control over the number of decimal places that are displayed.

Comment: For a paranoid solution: compute int(t * 18 + 320.5), convert to string and insert a decimal point.